# Recommended file permissions

Tags: 8, files

Similarly to what described in https://www.drupal.org/node/244924, which is for Drupal 7, is there any script to set the right permissions for Drupal 8?

How can we take care of the file permissions for contributed modules? For example, I know a few modules which would have different permissions for files like .htaccess and other private folders in the modules. Is there a way we can reset the file permissions to initial versions?

Comment: I have found no difference between permissions in Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.

Comment: Same, I think this article is pretty much valid for D8 as well.

Comment: The official guide has been ported to 8/9, but is still being worked on. [Securing file permissions and ownership](https://www.drupal.org/docs/security-in-drupal/securing-file-permissions-and-ownership)

Answer (score 1):

I've been running the same script included on that page for sites running either Drupal 7 or Drupal 8, with no adverse effects. I would recommend just using that.